# An integer with cubic root that is not constructible

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, cubics

Prove that for an integer $n$ which is not of the form $a^3$, $\sqrt[3]{n}$ is not constructible using that fact that if a cubic equation with rational coefficients has a constructible root then the equation has a rational root.

From what I gather a contradiction must be shown in that one side of the equation must be shown to be equal to an irrational number. Can someone show this proof?

Comment: What do you mean "constructible?" Do you mean straight-edge-and-compass?

Comment: Yes, for example if $a$ is contructible and so is $b$, then so is $a+b$. Or if $a$ is positive, then $\sqrt{a}$ is also constructible.

Comment: Presumably, you need some Galois Theory to prove this, since the impossibility of squaring a cube (the case of $n=2$) was not proven impossible until the theory.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is constructible, then $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ will be a power of $2$.

Comment: The question itself provides the necessary result from Galois theory.  The onus is really on OP to explain why they have not produced any attempt to use this fact.